# Error error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute' attribute on Runtime.OpenSilver.csproj

Tags: opensilver

In some configurations the compiler can lead to multiple errors that look like:

```
error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute' attribute [path\OpenSilverFramework\src\Runtime\Runtime\Runtime.OpenSilver.csproj]

The duplicate attribute can be different depending on the system.
```

In the Runtime.OpenSilver.csproj I've added two more directive to make it play more nicely with mixed solution (.net and .net core):

`<PropertyGroup> <GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>false</GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute> <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo> </PropertyGroup>`

That way the error disappear.

Answer (score 0):

As I mention by adding these two directives, I prevent visual studio to generate duplicate attributes.

```
<PropertyGroup> <GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>false</GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute> <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo> </PropertyGroup>
```

That way the error disappears.